# Filter specific columns

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have these kind of data rows

```
0 0 8 85 105 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 51 41 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 24 264 223 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 6 58 65 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 50 98 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How can I find the two largest numbers (and one before them and one after them), and their position in a record? And If I have only this (just one value)

```
0 0 0 100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

print out just the one maximum and before one, after two values

I should get this:

```
# [position column index] [value] ...

3 8 4 85 5 105 6 7    # <--- 3rd colum value 8, 4th column value 85,...etc
3 0 4 51 5 41 6 5
2 24 3 264 4 223 5 12
2 6 3 58 4 65 5 0
2 0 3 50 4 98 5 0
3 0 4 100 5 0 6 0
```

Comment: I don't fully understand how you get from the input to the desired output

Comment: I have edited the post in the desired output...

Comment: what happens if you have a record like `6 24 264 264 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`? Good luck.

Comment: What if the two largest values are not consecutive, or they are at the start or end of the line?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this almost works, without the special cases like the one mentioned right below the question: `6 24 264 264 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`... actually your last line is also can cause a problem...

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "}
     { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {line[i]=$i}
       m1=0; m2=0
      for (e in line) { 
          if (m1 <= line[e]) { m1=line[e]; m1i=e } }
      for (e in line) { 
          if (m2 <= line[e] && line[e]<m1 ) { m2=line[e]; m2i=e } }
      if (m1i<=m2i) { first=m1i-1;last=m2i+1 } 
         else { first=m2i-1;last=m1i+1 }
      if (first<1) { first=1 }
      for (i=first;i<=last;i++) {printf("%s%s%s%s", i, FS, line[i], FS)}
      printf("\n")
}' FILE
```

See it in action here: http://ideone.com/pbpmO